# Meaning of the symbols used in Milky Way?

Tags: fairy-tail

In the new episode of Fairy Tail for 2014, Wendy uses a secret Dragon Slayer Art, Milky Way which grants her the power to communicate or call upon lost souls of dragons.

[image]

I couldn't help but notice the symbols. Is there some meaning behind it, are these required for this to work and is this a type of language?

What exactly are they? Are they suppose to mean anything, or are they just there for decoration?

Answers are appreciated. :)

Comment: Makes sense how she thought it was an offensive spell at first, because if you look back to her fight with Chelia, she says she hasn't mastered Milky Way yet so she uses Sky Drill. But after finding out what Milky Way does, it's like "why would she use that in a fight," ya know

Answer (score 5):

They aren't just symbols for decoration, but **actual words**. You can see how Wendy said she had made a mistake while writing a certain word, thinking it was an offensive spell at first. Since Milky way isn't your average spell, it looks like you need a very specific magic circle to use it. I couldn't find what language they were written in though.

[image: enter image description here!]